# ALTER DATABASE script preventing restore of MySQL database in another server

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysqldump, restore

While backing up the database with **mysqldump --routines** options, I see ALTER DATABASE in the middle of the output dump, near the routines.

```
/*!50003 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `f_my_function` */;
ALTER DATABASE `my_database` CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
```

The database character set is set to utf8.
Presence of this line is preventing the restore of the database in another system.

What is the fault?

Answer (score 2):

The problem rests with the character set of [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/routines-table.html)

Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES\G` and you should see

```
mysql> show create table information_schema.routines\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: ROUTINES
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `ROUTINES` (
  `SPECIFIC_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_CATALOG` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_TYPE` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DATA_TYPE` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` int(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH` int(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMERIC_PRECISION` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMERIC_SCALE` int(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATETIME_PRECISION` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHARACTER_SET_NAME` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COLLATION_NAME` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DTD_IDENTIFIER` longtext,
  `ROUTINE_BODY` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` longtext,
  `EXTERNAL_NAME` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXTERNAL_LANGUAGE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PARAMETER_STYLE` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IS_DETERMINISTIC` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SQL_DATA_ACCESS` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SQL_PATH` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SECURITY_TYPE` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CREATED` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `LAST_ALTERED` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `SQL_MODE` varchar(8192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_COMMENT` longtext NOT NULL,
  `DEFINER` varchar(77) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COLLATION_CONNECTION` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DATABASE_COLLATION` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

In order to load the routines into your new system, you can filter it using [**grep**](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_grep.htm)

## EXAMPLE

Suppose the script with the ALTER DATABASE is `mydata.sql`. Just do this

```
grep -v "^ALTER DATABASE" mydata.sql | mysql -uroot -p...
```

This will bypass running the [`ALTER DATABASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-database.html).

Why is [`ALTER DATABASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-database.html) included ? According to the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html)

> mysqldump output can include ALTER DATABASE statements that change the database collation. These may be used when dumping stored programs to preserve their character encodings. To reload a dump file containing such statements, the ALTER privilege for the affected database is required.

The database's character set and collation must have been `CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci` when you dumped from it. My guess is that the dump originated from a Windows version of MySQL .

Comment: The client was Linux (old setup). In the routines table structure, a lot of columns were missing.

DATA_TYPE, 
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH, 
NUMERIC_PRECISION, 
NUMERIC_SCALE, 
DATETIME_PRECISION, 
CHARACTER_SET_NAME, 
COLLATION_NAME.

The new host was definitely a newer version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

With your hints, I found out what went wrong.
The database collation was changed to utf8 after the routine was created in old database with latin.

```
SELECT routine_name, COLLATION_CONNECTION, DATABASE_COLLATION FROM information_schema.ROUTINES WHERE routine_schema=DATABASE();
```

In this case, COLLATION_CONNECTION and DATABASE_COLLATION were not matching for the function that caused this issue. Later on, I had to drop the old function and simply recreate it with the same query body.